# Laravel - Getting wrong guard model when I try to use multi authentication

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with Laravel 5.7 multi-auth implementation.

I have created a new table for backend login: "AdminUsers".

So, I modified auth.php file:

```
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Ecommerce\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'table'  => Ecommerce\AdminUser::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Then, I create the AdminLoginController class:

```
<?php

namespace Ecommerce\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Ecommerce\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;


class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/index';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }


    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard('admin')->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }


    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        dd('authenticated!');
    }


    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

}
```

I setted this routes in routes file:

```
Route::get ('/login', ['uses'=>'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm'])->name('login_page');
Route::post('/login', ['uses'=>'Auth\AdminLoginController@login'        ])->name('do_login'  );
```

The problem is, that when I do login, Laravel tries to use "users" guard instead of the defined "admin" guard. So that throw a SQL error (because I have not created the "Users" table in the DB).

Even if I do `var_dump($this->guard('admin'))` inside `AdminLoginController::attemptLogin` method, the response gives me a SessionGuard object with "`Ecommerce\User`" instead of "`Ecommerce\AdminUser`" that is the one defined as "admin" in auth.php guard array.

Anyone knows where else can I look to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've noticed a difference in the providers section: 'table'  => Ecommerce\AdminUser::class. Is it 'table' or 'model'?

Comment: Have you tried adding `protected $guard = 'admin'` in your AdminController?

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez It was that: "table" instead of "model". Six hours looking and digging into tons of code... I feel like a stupid newbie! Than you very much!

Comment: To be honest, i did not have a clue but that just looked a bit weird. Glad to have helped! Let me post the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your auth.php providers section.

```
'table'  => Ecommerce\AdminUser::class
```

'table' should be replaced with 'model'.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was that. I feel like a newbie :P.